# Having problems understanding checked radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate my form through JavaScript and instead of manually checking each radio button I decided to loop through a group of radio buttons and check to see if they were checked or not.

I'm simply trying to see if a group of radio buttons is checked or not. But the problem I'm facing is. It's returning both true and false when I check either of them. If I don't check either, they both return false but if I check one, it returns true and false.

Here is my code:

```js
function validateForm(){
 let firstliGroup = document.getElementsByName("yesnocheck");

 for(i=0; i<firstliGroup.length; i++){
  //console.log(firstliGroup[i].checked);
  if(firstliGroup[i].checked == true){
   console.log('success');
   return true;
  }
  else {
   console.log('failed');
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="driverkeylistform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
 <fieldset id="group1">
  <input type="radio" name="yesnocheck" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span>
  <input type="radio" name="yesnocheck" value="No"><span>No</span>
 </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: The form is submitting if "yes" is selected.... I'm not sure what problem you are facing....

Comment: 1 second let me check something real quick.

Comment: Seems to be showing "true" in the console and then submitting the form. I'm going by the snippet you have provided when running it and I am only selecting from the first set of radio buttons since those are the only ones your javascript is targeting. The rest are irrelevant.

Comment: I edited my question I don't know if that was more clearer. I can also show a console log if thats more helpful

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[name=yesnocheck]:checked').length` (should only return one entry for radios of the same name if checked).

Comment: You `return` after checking the first element, regardless of whether it's true or false. You might move the `return false` outside of the `for` loop. But yes, as @JaredFarrish suggested, there are more efficient ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getRadioValue(name) {

    let elements = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].checked) {
            return elements[i].value;
        }
    }

    return null;

}

function validateForm() {

    var yesnocheck = getRadioValue("yesnocheck");
    console.log(yesnocheck);

    return false;

}
```

If nothing is checked, then getRadioValue function will return null.
If any option was checked, it will return it's value.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.forms[0].yesnocheck`.

```js
function validateForm()
{
    return (document.forms[0].yesnocheck.value.length  > 0 &&
            document.forms[0].yesnoremote.value.length > 0 &&
            document.forms[0].yesnocable.value.length  > 0 &&
            document.forms[0].condition.value.length   > 0);
}
```

```html
<form name="driverkeylistform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
 <fieldset id="group1">
  <input type="radio" name="yesnocheck" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span>
  <input type="radio" name="yesnocheck" value="No"><span>No</span>
 </fieldset>
  <label for="gateremote">Gate remote batteries checked?:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="yesnoremote" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span>
  <input type="radio" name="yesnoremote" value="No"><span>No</span>

  <label for="internetcabletv">Internet and Cable TV checked?:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="yesnocable" value="Yes"><span>Yes</span>
  <input type="radio" name="yesnocable" value="No"><span>No</span>

  <label for="unitcondition">Unit Condition?:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="condition" value="clean"><span>Clean</span>
  <input type="radio" name="condition" value="light"><span>Light</span>
  <input type="radio" name="condition" value="heavy"><span>Heavy</span>
  <input type="radio" name="condition" value="superheavy"><span>SuperHeavy</span>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```